# Problem in converting from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert this code from C# to VB. Tried to use third party tools, but not successful. Can some one help me .Thanks

```
private static string RemoveInvalidHtmlTags(this string text)
{
    return HtmlTagExpression.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator((Match m) =>
    {
        if (!ValidHtmlTags.ContainsKey(m.Groups["tag"].Value))
            return String.Empty;

        string generatedTag = String.Empty;

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group tagStart = m.Groups["tag_start"];
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group tagEnd = m.Groups["tag_end"];
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group tag = m.Groups["tag"];
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group tagAttributes = m.Groups["attr"];

        generatedTag += (tagStart.Success ? tagStart.Value : "<");
        generatedTag += tag.Value;

        foreach (Capture attr in tagAttributes.Captures)
        {
            int indexOfEquals = attr.Value.IndexOf('=');

            // don't proceed any futurer if there is no equal sign or just an equal sign
            if (indexOfEquals < 1)
                continue;

            string attrName = attr.Value.Substring(0, indexOfEquals);

            // check to see if the attribute name is allowed and write attribute if it is
            if (ValidHtmlTags[tag.Value].Contains(attrName))
                generatedTag += " " + attr.Value;
        }

        // add nofollow to all hyperlinks
        //if (tagStart.Success && tagStart.Value == "<" && tag.Value.Equals("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        //    generatedTag += " rel=\"nofollow\"";

        if (tag.Value.ToString() == "object")
        {
            generatedTag += (tagEnd.Success ? " height=\"374\" width=\"416\"" + tagEnd.Value : ">");
        }
        else
        {
            generatedTag += (tagEnd.Success ? tagEnd.Value : ">");
        }


        return generatedTag;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Which part(s) cause you problems?

Comment: Why not compile to IL and then use a reflector?

Comment: Problem is between line 3 and 5. vb conversion says -- line 4 col 5: VB does not support anonymous methods/lambda expressions with a statement body.

Comment: Ipthnc - Dont know how to "compile to IL and use a reflector" ??. Can you explain in detail.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568526/convert-c-statement-body-lambda-to-vb).

Comment: Yes, read this: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/10/converting-between-vb-and-c-and-net-decompilation.html

Comment: Ipthnc - I will check on it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem converting this code is that you have a lambda expression with a multi-line statement body:

```
(Match m) =>
{
    ...a lot of code
}
```

Since VB9 doesn't support this, you'll want to put the code in brackets into its own function instead:

```
Private Function GetValue(m As Match) As String
   ....a lot of code
End Function
```

Then your RemoveInvalidHtmlTags code will look like this:

```
Return HtmlTagExpression.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(AddressOf GetValue))
```

You can use free tools to translate the rest of the code.

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: +1. That's what the error message quoted by the OP means: "VB does not support anonymous methods/lambda expressions with a statement body"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this [free tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)?

Comment: Yes, i have used the same tool to convert. but is giving me an error.